# how could I rewind my work on top of FETCH_HEAD

Tags: git

After I pulled from the remote repository, I got the following messages:

> - branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it... Fast-forwarded my_topic to
>     f05183b231e55864ae8d99db9456167af3413b6a

So how could I rewind my work on top of FETCH_HEAD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message is a confirmation of what git has successfully done - it isn't asking you to do anything.

if you want to check that a branch contains a particular commit:

```
git branch --contains <hash>
```

*It's not related to the question as asked* but if you want to put commits ontop of others - that's where `git rebase` comes in - to re-order commits.

e.g.

```
git checkout master
...
git commit -vam "one"
...
git commit -vam "two"
...
git checkout somebranch
...
git commit -vam "three"
...
git commit -vam "four"
```

Commits one+two and three+four are in 2 separate branches. to get them in order:

```
git rebase master
```

Alternatively, you can apply a single commit simply by doing:

```
git cherry-pick <hash>
```

You can use `git reflog` to find the hash for any commit that you think is missing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I have made some mistakes that I pulled the remote repository to a new branch so that I could not see my own work on that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add and commit everything on your own side first? To check that, do a

```
git status
```

If you didn't, you should always do that first and then try pulling again.

Comment: I did. But I can't see my commits on `git log`. But I can see these commits on `git reflog`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, if you're still having problems maybe try resetting it to the last commit available on git reflog? eg. after doing a `git reflog`, find the commit you want to reset to and do a `git reset --hard [sha1 of commit]`.

Comment: I don't have anything to commit, even those I will get that message